# UIBarButtonItem Not Working Input Accesory View iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I have a dismiss button that is a UIBarButtonItem, which is added to a UIToolbar, which is added to a text boxes inputAccessoryView.

It worked find in iOS 6, but since iOS 7 the Button doesn't act like a button, its just text.

Here is what it looks like in iOS 6.

[image]

Here is what it looks like in iOS 7

[image]

It doesn't act like a button anymore, and when I try to click it I just click the icon behind the Dismiss text.

Here is the code for this portion of the app:

```
self.searchBox.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
self.searchBox.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
self.searchBox.delegate = self;

UIToolbar* searchToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]init];
searchToolbar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem       alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Dismiss" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneWithKeyboard)];

[searchToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace, doneButton, nil]];

self.searchBox.inputAccessoryView = searchToolbar;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That hows buttons look in iOS 7.

Comment: But it doesn't act like a button...I can't click it. It just clicks whats behind the word dismiss.

Comment: Where's the toolbar? That seems to be the issue. It doesn't appear (with it's black tint) in the iOS 7 image.

Comment: I don't know why the toolbar isn't showing up. The code is the same for both images.

Comment: The toolbars frame wasn't initialized. Add the "where's your toolbar" answer and I'll accept.